# V10 - VB.NET >Validação de User/Password Correta

Tags: vb.net

Estou a tentar validar o user e password se estão corretos.
O Código é este:

```
Dim adm As New AdmEngine100.clsUtilizadores
Dim statusLogin As AdmEngine100.clsUtilizadores.EnumLogin

        statusLogin = adm.Login(user, PWD)
```

O erro que aparece é:

> A Referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto.

O que poderá faltar no código?

Comment: Olá Paulo, com esse código apenas fica dificil perceber o erro. É um projeto de extensibilidade ou de integração? Fazes a abertura da plataforma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estive a testar consegui o que pretendes da seguinte forma:

Estancio o StdPlatBS

```
Dim plataforma = New StdPlatBS()
```

Valido o login:

```
Dim login As Object = plataforma.Administrador.ListaUtilizadores.Login(user, pwd)
```